# nasm (x86_64 System V ABI) portable way to determine the stack memory used?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am currently toying around with some ideas about how to implement a variable size stack for a fiber/coroutine implementation and was wondering if there is a portable way to determine the current stack memory in use. My initial idea was to subtract the stack top `rsp` from `rbp` which holds the current stack bottom (but based on my research there seem to be very little guarantees). Is there a better way? Will I have to manually save the last stack top and retrieve it to do this calculation?

Thanks

Comment: `rbp` isn't the bottom of the stack; it's just the bottom of your function's stack frame. And even that's not required; for example, C compilers often just use it as any other register when optimizing.

Comment: Thanks, after letting this sink in a little more I am pretty sure I'd have to manually keep track of this.

Comment: Yup, you need to separately find out where the highest stack address is, or where the lowest address is for your stack mapping so you can see directly how close to it you are.  But for the main thread's stack, dynamic growth means that bottom won't show up in /proc/self/maps.  If you take the address of a local in `main`, or `argv[0]`, that might be a reasonable proxy for the highest address in the stack (the bottom).